# Are dropped packages in traffic control really dropped?

Tags: tc

While having a slight timeout problem in my network (the router needed some rest, so that's solved) I found myself trying to decipher `tc -s` output, after noticing that the "dropped" values represented an important proportion of packages, of at least 10%:

```
qdisc cbq 1: root refcnt 2 rate 10Mbit (bounded,isolated) prio no-transmit
 Sent 392050166 bytes 727491 pkt (dropped 27505, overlimits 1201372 requeues 1) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 1 
  borrowed 0 overactions 0 avgidle 12500 undertime 0
qdisc sfq 10: parent 1:10 limit 127p quantum 1514b depth 127 divisor 1024 perturb 10sec 
 Sent 16125105 bytes 265435 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc sfq 20: parent 1:20 limit 127p quantum 1514b depth 127 divisor 1024 perturb 10sec 
 Sent 375890855 bytes 461738 pkt (dropped 27505, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc sfq 30: parent 1:30 limit 127p quantum 1514b depth 127 divisor 1024 perturb 10sec 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc ingress ffff: parent ffff:fff1 ---------------- 
 Sent 342713979 bytes 716041 pkt (dropped 1308, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

So, these counters represent really dropped package, *a la* iptables? Or it's just a representation of something else? What represent this number?

The manual says something about dropping, but it left me with the same doubt:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Tc is used to configure Traffic Control in the Linux kernel. Traffic Control consists of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> DROPPING
>
> Traffic exceeding a set bandwidth may also be dropped forthwith, both on ingress and on egress.

Answer (score 1):

A dropped packet is discarded. It won't reach its destination. This can happen at any point in a switch or router where bandwidth is exceeded. It's the responsibility of the receiving system to track the incoming packets and make sure it has them all. TCP does this but UDP does not. Dropped packets must be requested from the sending station again, so on a busy route the dropped packets can lead to more congestion and more dropped packets.